# Let$x_1,x_2,…,x_7$ be the roots of: $10x^7+20x^6-573x^5-1146x^4+8951x^3+17902x^2-24738x-49476=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let$x_1,x_2,…,x_7$ be the roots of:
$$10x^7+20x^6-573x^5-1146x^4+8951x^3+17902x^2-24738x-49476=0$$
Find: $\sum[x_i]\quad$

> I know the relation between roots and coefficint of a polynomial equation I also know $[x]$and its properties. [x] is the greatest integer part of x.
>   The original question is slithly different.

Comment: Hint: $10\times 2=20, 573\times 2=1146$ etc so $-2$ is a root, and dividing by $x+2$ will give an factorisable polynomial of $x^2$

Comment: $(x + 2)  (x^2 - 31)  (5x^2 - 114)  (2x^2 - 7)$.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem without finding the roots

Comment: One way to solve to solve this for an arbitrary polynomial and without finding the roots is by evaluating a [Sturn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem) at the integer points between a [bound for the roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_all_roots). The changes in number of changes of signs of the sequence gives you how many roots are in each interval, and with this you find the sum of the integer parts.

Comment: Are you the Jabberwock?  The original word is slythy.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to avoid the root $-2$. For the other $6$ roots, you don't need their precise values. You only need to know you can group them into 3 pairs of the form $\pm r$ for some non-integer $r$. You then use the identity $\lfloor -r \rfloor + \lfloor r \rfloor = -1$ whenever $r$ is not an integer to conclude the sum of floor of roots is $-2 -3(1) = -5$